# what is the Bernoulli product measure's Radon-Nikodym derivative wrt Lebesgue measure?

Tags: probability, distributions, intuition, measure-theory, sigma-algebra

The Bernoulli product measure $\mu$ can be defined for each $p\in (0,1)$ on $\Omega = \{0,1\}^\mathbb N=\{\omega=(\omega_i)|\omega_i\in\{0,1\}, i\in\mathbb N\}=\Pi_{i=1}^\infty \{0,1\}$.  The measure $\mu$ is essentially defined by a collection of Bernoulli random variables $X_i:\Omega\to\{0,1\}$ which take the value $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$ depending only on the $i$th coordinate of $\omega\in\Omega$.  The pre-images $X_i^{-1}(0)$ and $X_i^{-1}(1)$ are examples of cylinder sets in the product space and generate the $\sigma$-algebra that the product measure $\mu$ is defined on.

We can then define a map $\Omega\to [0;1]\subset\mathbb R$ by $\omega=(\omega_i)\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^\infty \omega_i 2^{-i}$.  Up to a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ having to do with duplicate  binary expansions of the dyadic rationals $k/2^n$ ($k,n\in\mathbb N$), this map identifies $\Omega$ with the unit interval $[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$.  The duplicate issue is that dyadic rationals have both an infinite and a terminating binary expansion (in binary, $1/2=0.1=0.0\bar 1$), so the map is not a perfect bijection on that countable set.

We now have two measures on $[0;1]$, $\mu$ and Lebesgue measure $\cal L$.  They are defined on slightly different $\sigma$-algebras since $\cal L$ is defined on the Borel sets and $\mu$ is defined on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets that make the random variables $X_i$ measurable (generated by the cylinder sets).

Is there anything like a Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\cal L$ even though they are not defined on the same $\sigma$-algebras?  For example, is it possible to extend or intersect the $\sigma$-algebras to obtain a useful integral formula with an actual density function so that we could write $$\mu=\nu + \int f d\cal L$$ on some meaningful collection of sets? ($\nu$ a measure singular wrt $\cal L$)

I've looked in a number of books including Billingsley, Chung, Folland, Rudin, Durett, and others.  They discuss the construction of $\mu$, the differences of the $\sigma$-algebras that $\mu$ and $\cal L$ are defined on, but I haven't been able to find any kind of expression of one with respect to the other, if that's possible in some way.

My motivation is to get a better understanding of $\mu$ in more standard analytical terms.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Could you be more specific as to what you are seeking? Perhaps a bit more context.

Comment: To be more specific @User1865345-solidarityMods, I wonder if there exists a function $f$ such that $\mu = \nu + \int f d{\cal L}$ where $\nu$ is singular wrt ${\cal L}$, and if so, what is a closed form for $f$.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods, I expanded the question somewhat to include more definitions and background in case that's what you were referring to.

Comment: It's looking better. On another note, I would have asked it in Maths.

Comment: fair point thanks - I'll look to see if there's a site-supported way to cross-post or if it's just copy-paste.

Comment: Currently, it's discouraged to have any cross-posting. While there are decent number of users knowledgeable in measure and ergodic theory here, imo, this could be better answered at Maths.

Comment: ok thanks I moved the question to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725645/what-is-the-bernoulli-product-measures-radon-nikodym-derivative-wrt-lebesgue-me